# scrapy misses xpaths where xpath contains cp1251

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy, cp1251

Values response:

```
{
 'articul': [u'testetete'],
 'diametr': ['Empty'],
 'image': [u'/foto/11.20.jpg'],
 'name': [u'Трололололо'],
 'url': ['http://test.ru/goods/detali.html?product_id=20']
}
```

where other fields?

Comment: Maybe the other data is not present in the response?  You will have to provide a snippet of the response body or maybe the url of the website in question.

Comment: Please, provide the full code of ur web scraper (or spider).

Answer (score 0):

It's because `add_xpath` method gets XPath as argument only. If you need to add another one (such as "Масса" or "Состав") to value that spider takes from xpath, you can add it to [pipelines.py](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) , or to your another module, that takes results from Spider.